# Google Chrome running super slow

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, performance

Today I started my computer as usual. And opened the **Google Chrome browser** and found that I was running **SUPER slow**.

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**
(1) Create a new browser window
(2) Choose File -> New Tab

**What is the expected output?**

The NTP page should display instantaneously

**What do you see instead?**

The NTP takes a full 1 second to appear. By "appear" I mean the new tab appears with blan content instantly, but then you wait 1s for the NTP page contents to finally show up.

Attached is a trace - see pid 47093. It shows two NTP loads, one at 5.5s and the second at 8.5s. It shows the page taking about 200ms to load, followed by a CSS animation that runs for 1.1s (according to the red boxes along the top).

---

I'm using:

- Windows 10 (64-bit)
- Google Chrome v49.0.2623.112 m (64-bit) *(last version)*

  - Extensions: ad-block
- PC:

  - CPU AMD FX-8320 (3.5GHz)
  - RAM 8GB

---

**Edit**

Is a bug.

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599872
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599212

Comment: If you boot (Windows) into a minimal configuration does this behavior still exhibit itself?  Have you tried running Chrome without any plugins?

Comment: Is Chrome updated to the latest version?

Comment: @Moab Well Chrome 49 is the current version

Comment: @Ramhound No i didn't try to boot windows with minimal configuration. Yes i tried running chome without any plugins.

Comment: @Moab yes chrome is in the last version.

Comment: @Ramhound i just tried the minimal configuration booting, but the problem persists.

Comment: "Super slow" is really vague.

Comment: @Ramhound I open a new tab and i need to wait 4 tics to start writing.

Comment: You have tried an entirely new profile, not just disabling an add on, but wipe the profile that exists and let chrome create a new one?  Have you verified this problem does not exist for Firefox or Edge?

Comment: @Ramhound all that i did it. I checked track issuse of chrome/chromium and im not the only guy how has this problem.

Comment: I updated the post, is a bug of chrome.

Comment: The big seems to indicate it's connect to flash PPAPI

Comment: Is like chinese for me. I did try to disable PPAPI in chrome://flags but didn't fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38195/discussion-between-wakematta-and-ramhound).